# Less CSS : Conditional @imports using mixins - Variable scope

Tags: less

What I'm attempting to do is `@import` specific files into my Less project by setting checking for specific variables. This is what I have so far:

```
@import "shared/variables";
@import "shared/global";
@import "shared/hero";
@import "shared/listings";

//
// Color Variations
// Based on @bt-color-variation
// Decides when to load the light/dark theme
//
@bt-color-variation: dark; // Default color variation
.bt-color-variation(dark) {
    @import "color-variations/dark/global";

    @import "color-variations/dark/variables";
}

.bt-color-variation(dark) {
    @import "color-variations/light/global";
    @import "color-variations/light/buttons.less";

    @import "color-variations/light/variables";
}

.bt-color-variation(@bt-color-variation);
```

This does in-fact load the appropriate color variations based on that variable. The issue is that any variables set within that color variation's `variable.less` file are not overriding what is done outside of it in the `shared/variables.less` file. It seems like there's an issue with either "when" mixins are run compared to the regular `@imports` or a scope issue. I was hoping the mixins would run after and use Less's "last-win" case for variables.

Any ideas with how I'd conditionally load files based on a Less variable (and not deal with variable scope) would be EXTREMELY helpful. Thanks as always.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables from within mixins do not override those in the caller scope (see [Mixins as Functions](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-as-functions-feature)).

For this use-case I'd suggest something more simple:

```
@bt-color-variation: dark;

@import "color-variations/@{bt-color-variation}/global";
@import "color-variations/@{bt-color-variation}/buttons";
@import "color-variations/@{bt-color-variation}/variables";
```

See [Variabes > Import statements](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements).

Comment: how would you go about this if there is no file to be imported when the condition isn't met?

Comment: `@bt-color-variation: default;` and provide (possibly empty) `@import "color-variations/default/global";` etc. files (or use `(optional)` flag instead of empty files). Though in a long run make sure you *don't* go the same road as in [#2772](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2772).

Comment: I think Ive tried everything, none of those seem to be working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460595/optional-imports-in-less