# less @import directive in mixin guard

Tags: less

I have one main.less file that imports all the other less files of my project.
I would like to choose which less files should be requested by the browser according to a variable:

```
@direction: rtl;
.imports(@direction) when (@direction = rtl) {
    @import "components/grid.import.less";
    @import "components/grid-rtl.import.less";
}
.imports(@direction) {
    @import "components/grid.import.less";
}
.imports(@direction);
```

This works when `@direction` at the beginning of the file is set to `rtl` but when it is set to `ltr` no imported file are requested by the browser.

Let me know how can I achieve importing less files using if/else statement.

Thanks

Comment: Multiple imports require [`multiple`](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-multiple) option (*regardless* of any conditions - because imports are evaluated no matter if particular mixin definition is expanded or not). Though in this particular case you can simplify your snippet to something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/8bf67893ae56dcde61ec) and don't really need any multiple imports.

Comment: I need the less files to be requested in a specific order. Therefore I can't have only the rtl less files in a separated mixin and get the other mixin always called. I need either the first mixin to be called (without rtl files) or the second one (with regular files + rtl ones in a specific order)

Comment: The code in my example does *exacly* what your above snippet does. It imports both files when `direction` is `rtl` and only `grid.import.less` otherwise (and the order of imports is also identical to what you have above).

Comment: You are right in the case I have only one import in each mixin, but in the real life example I have: `@direction: rtl; .imports(...) { @import "components/check.less"; @import "components/grid.less"; } .imports(rtl) { @import "components/check-rtl.less"; @import "components/grid-rtl.less"; } .imports(@direction);` and I would like them to be requested in the browser in the following order when direction is rtl: check, check-rtl, grid, grid-rtl, With your solution I will get: check, grid, check-rtl, grid-rtl. Since the order is important your solution doesn't work for me. Am I right?

Comment: Well, read my first comment again: your initial code will work if you add `multiple` option. As for importing a lot of files with shuffled order - hmm, (while it still possible with "my" method) but why don't you split those into different files? (e.g. `normal-imports.less` and `rtl-imports.less`... and then using those depending on what CSS sub-project you compile? e.g .see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664587. "Thinking in `if`s" is not always a good idea in declarative languages like CSS or Less).