# Conditionally using .less stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, less

I'm trying to master Less and need help.

I have three stylesheets for different parts of the same application.
Lets call them `1.less, 2.less, 3.less`. I also have a `shared.less` stylesheet, which contains some common styles for all three parts.

I want to use these files in main stylesheet `application.css` via `require`.

How can I switch between these `1.less`, `2.less` and `3.less` in the `application.css`?

Like

`*= require yfu_app/shared.less
*= require yfu_app/1.less` when 1st part of the app is used;

`*= require yfu_app/shared.less
*= require yfu_app/2.less` when 2nd part of the app is used and so on.

May be there is a better way of doing it?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to `@import` less files conditionally into `shared.less`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition in your layout application.html.erb to pick stylesheet as per your app page

for an example

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application' %>
<% if less_1 %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'less1' %>   
<% elsif less_2 %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'less2' %>   
<% elsif less_3 %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'less1' %>   
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I do not want to change the layout file.

Comment: @AnnaKizilova its only way, you can't give conditions to app.css file

Comment: is it possible to do it another way? Please look at the edit

Comment: @AnnaKizilova Not sure its possible or not, but you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26666354 , it will help you

Comment: @AnnaKizilova can you please also upvote this answer so it will help other users in future ?